# Solving these equations with a constraint

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I have been for long time now try to solve this equation

```
q1[t_] = D[x[t], t, t] - 2 (1/y[t]) D[y[t], t] D[x[t], t]
```

With its complex conjugate

```
q2[t_] = Conjugate[D[x[t], t, t]] - 2 (1/Conjugate[y[t]]) 
         Conjugate[D[y[t], t]] Conjugate[D[x[t], t]]
```

In `y[t]` and `x[t]` , where:

```
y[t] D[x[t], t] Conjugate[D[x[t], t]] = Exp[-100 t]
```

I tried `NDSolve` with arbitrary initial conditions, but nothing worked with me. According to the above constraint, I should get both `y` and `x` varying with time.

Any help how to make this work, even with solving analytically by `DSolve` or `Reduce` ?

Comment: Pleased show what you have tried so far.IT IS unclear which ode you intend to solve.

Comment: Well, with all due respect, as a member for 5 years, you should have format this question better. This time I've done it for you, but please take some time to learn to [format the code properly](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). Also, have a look at [this](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2126/1871).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We write the first equation in the form

```
eq1 = {D[x[t], t, t] - 2 D[Log[y[t]], t] D[x[t], t] == 0
```

In the second equation, we take the logarithm and differentiate, then we have

```
eq2=D[Log[y[t]], t] == -100 - D[Log[Abs[D[x[t], t]]^2], t]
```

Further suppose that `x[t]` is real. We substitute expression `D[Log[y[t]], t]` from the second equation into the first and add the initial data, then we get

```
eq1 = {x''[t] + 2 (100 + D[Log[x'[t]^2], t]) x'[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, 
   x'[0] == 1};
sol = NDSolveValue[eq1, x, {t, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
LogLogPlot[sol[t], {t, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "x"}]

LogLogPlot[Exp[-100 t]/sol'[t]^2, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 200, AxesLabel -> {"t", "y"}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thanks so much. @AlexTrounev

Comment: @Dr.phy You're welcome!